# How to disable submitting in edit text on enter hit

Tags: android, kotlin

I have few edit texts in a vertical row and when I press enter it submits the field and changes row

I want to disable it, any suggestions?

Comment: Then what's the behavior you want?

Comment: I don't wan't any behavior on enter pressed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            //do your stuff       
        }

        return true;        //handle only by this event listener
    }
});
```